# Override the emptiness check for an Object, for using JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, jackson, jackson-databind

I've following 2 objects

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
@Data
Class Alpha{

  String a;
  String b;
  String c;
}

@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
@Data
Class Gamma{

  String xxx;
  Alpha alpha;
  String yyy;
}
```

Now if Gamma is my API response and its instantiated as following.

```
Gamma gamma = new Gamma();
gamma.setXxx("val1");
gamma.setYyy("val2");
gamma.setAlpha(new Alpha()); // For this example all values in alpha are null
```

I this case API client gets this response

```
{
  "xxx": "val1",
  "yyy": "val2",
  "alpha":{}
}
```

The empty "alpha" property here is the problem.

**The ideal solution**
Idel way is, to not initialize an empty `Alpha` object if all its properties are null.
But I oversimplified my application logic for the question.
I have some backend code which, in some scenarios can have an empty `Alpha` object.

**My Question is**
For an object of type `Alpha` , How can I override the behavior of how jackson check for non-emptiness of this object when `JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY` is present

Like overriding/Annotating some `isEmpty()` method. But only for specific Class.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
@Data
Class Gamma{

  String xxx;
  @JsonInclude(value = JsonInclude.Include.CUSTOM, valueFilter = Alpha.class)
  Alpha alpha;
  String yyy;
}
```